# How to create nested arrays out of an existing array

Tags: ruby

If I have

```
arr = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"]
```

how can I make `arr` equal to this?

```
[["a", "b"], ["c", "d"], ["e", "f"]]
```

the goal is to use arr.to_h to make it all into a hash.  Thanks!

Comment: What is the code you are having trouble with? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ? Please, provide a [mre]. Please be aware that [so] is not a code-writing service, you need to show your efforts!

Comment: https://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/ https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/ https://idownvotedbecau.se/nomcve/

Comment: Your question should be something like, "How to convert an array to a hash". You have made a classic error in assuming that a particular intermediate calculation is required (converting the array to an array of 2-element arrays). As you see from Dmitry's answer, that intermediate step is not needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Hash[]](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Hash.html#method-c-5B-5D)

```rb
Hash[*arr] #=> {"a"=>"b", "c"=>"d", "e"=>"f"}
```

Another option is [Enumerable#each_slice](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_slice)

```rb
arr.each_slice(2).to_h #=> {"a"=>"b", "c"=>"d", "e"=>"f"}
```

Comment: thank you so much! that worked